# Move Rows Up and Down in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to learn to move a row with in a gridview up and down the list by pressing either an up button or down button.

**Below is my ASP.NET.**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridChecks" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="GridChecks_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="gridChecks_RowCommand" Style="margin: 0 auto; width: 850px; margin-top: 10px" CssClass="tableGlobalGenericStyle tableGlobalOption_AlternatingRow">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Check ID" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Title" HeaderStyle-Width="250px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckTitle" runat="server" Width="240px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective From">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:textbox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:textbox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective To">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:textbox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:textbox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" HeaderStyle-Width="200px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnMoveUp" runat="server" CommandName="Up" CssClass="imageButton imageButton_UpArrow imageButton_Image" ToolTip="Click to add move check up the list" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnMoveDown" runat="server" CommandName="Down" CssClass="imageButton imageButton_DownArrow imageButton_Image" ToolTip="Click to add move check down the list" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveCheck" runat="server" OnClick="BtnRemove_Click" CssClass="imageButton imageButton_Remove imageButton_Image" ToolTip="Click to add remove check from the list" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddCheck" runat="server" OnClick="BtnAddCheck_Click" CssClass="imageButton imageButton_Add" Text="Add Check" ToolTip="Click to add new check to the list" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I currently have a delete button that deletes it from the row and retains the number sequence ID.

**Delete Button C#**

```
protected void BtnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button lb = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
    int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                //Remove the Selected Row data and reset row number
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
                ResetRowID(dt);
            }
        }

        //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        //Re bind the GridView for the updated data
        gridChecks.DataSource = dt;
        gridChecks.DataBind();
    }

    //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
    SetPreviousData();
}
```

I am trying to do something similar but move the row up or down in the list, also retaining the number sequence ID.

I have an understanding it will involve the indexes of the gridview and that i will need to rebind it once done.

Can someone **please** guide me in the right direction with an example. Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move the rows in the GridView Up and Down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994371/how-to-move-the-rows-in-the-gridview-up-and-down)

Comment: You will need to save the changes into database. Otherwise, it won't persist the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your example, given **index** is the index of the first of the two rows you want to swap:

create a new row

```
var firstRow = dt[index];
var newRow = dt.NewRow();
```

populate newRow with data from the first row

```
for (int i=0; i<dt.Colums.Count(); i++)
  newRow[i]=firstRow[i]
```

Remove firstRow

```
dt.RemoveAt[index];
```

Now second row has rowIndex = index, so we add new row after it

```
dt.InsertAt[newRow, index + 1];
```

In this way we have pulled up second row by 1 position

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lstup.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstup.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                if (i > 0 && !lstup.Items[i - 1].Selected)
                {
                    ListItem bottom = lstup.Items[i];

                    lstup.Items.Remove(bottom);
                    lstup.Items.Insert(i - 1, bottom);

                }
            }
        }
```